# Flutter apk showing only a blank screen w

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, build, apk

I am trying to create an apk for my flutter project but when I install it it shows either a plain blank screen or just the appbar.

The app is working fine when I run it through an emulator but the apk's seem to be the problem. When installing the app-release.apk it is installing just fine but I get the blank screen.Then when trying to install the app-debug.apk it is refusing to install and saying incompatible with device.

Here is the main.dart file

```
import 'package:finsec_private_markets_app/Pages/onboarding.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Sizer(builder: (context, orientation, deviceType) {
      return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: LandingPage(),
      );
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the landingpage file

```
import 'package:finsec_private_markets_app/Enterprise/stage_one.dart';
import 'package:finsec_private_markets_app/Enterprise/stage_option.dart';
import 'package:finsec_private_markets_app/Pages/enterprise_registration.dart';
import 'package:finsec_private_markets_app/Pages/enterprise_registration.dart';
import 'package:finsec_private_markets_app/Tests/test2.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sizer/sizer.dart';

import '../Constants/colors.dart';
import 'analyst_registration.dart';
import 'financier_registration.dart';

class LandingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const LandingPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<LandingPage> createState() => _LandingPageState();
}

class _LandingPageState extends State<LandingPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 8.h,
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [grad1, grad2], // Replace with your desired colors
              begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
              end: Alignment.centerRight,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        title: Center(
          child: Container(
              height: 120.h,
              child: Image.asset('assets/finsec.png', fit: BoxFit.contain)),
        ),
      ),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
              height: 100.h,
              width: 100.w,
              child: Image.asset('assets/darklanding.png', fit: BoxFit.cover)),
          Column(
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.h),
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    "WELCOME TO FINSEC PRIVATE MARKETS",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 14.sp,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 3.h,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 89.w,
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  child: Text(
                    'The FINSEC Private Market is a market place that brings together private companies and the investors seeking alternative investment opportunities through a digital platform called GEM-Portal',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 11.sp, color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              _blackbutton(
                  text: "Register as an Enterprise",
                  page: EnterpriseRegistrationPage(),
                  context: context),
              _blackbutton(
                  text: "Register as a Financier",
                  page: FinancierRegistrationPage(),
                  context: context),
              _blackbutton(
                  text: "Register as an Analyst",
                  page: AnalystRegistrationPage(),
                  context: context),
              const Spacer(),
              Container(
                width: 100.w,
                height: 9.h,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                  colors: [grad1, grad2],
                )),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
  }
}

Widget _blackbutton({text, context, page}) {
  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 5.h),
    child: SizedBox(
      height: 7.h,
      width: 30.h,
      child: ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (_) => page,
            ),
          );
        },
        child: Text(
          text,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
        ),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          side: const BorderSide(color: Colors.white),
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: Which version of Android do your Phone have and which version do the emulator have and for which version are you creating for?

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am facing the same issue.